# How to enable contentediaible for dragable rows of table in html/css/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I have a table with a column editible. When I use example from [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmw57/tzYbU/205/) to make rows of table dragable.

The contenteditable attribute is not working. This is [my JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiehu567/otenxyyk/)

If you comment out the javascript, you can see the column year is editible, but if you want to add the javascript to make row dragable, then the year column is not editible, though the attribute "contenteditible = 'true' is in page source code.

Here's my html for reference:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="sort" class="grid" title="Kurt Vonnegut novels">
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">1</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1969</p></td><td>Slaughterhouse-Five</td><td>A+</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">2</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1952</p></td><td>Player Piano</td><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">3</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1963</p></td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>A+</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">4</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1973</p></td><td>Breakfast of Champions</td><td>C</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">5</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1965</p></td><td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td><td>A</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

jQuery:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
};

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: no, the attribute is still in clone, if I add debugger there and check tr.clone() or $helper

Comment: Clicking is the start of being able to drag something.  It's a conflict with the plugin intercepting this event in order to know what to drag.

Comment: @Taplar, your comment make sense. So how I can make double click to trigger edit? Tnx

Comment: It might be easier to put the elements into input fields and css style them to have a border-width of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues here:

1. Add a cancel option on the contenteditable items.
2. Remove disableSelection() as it makes the target item lose focus.

```js
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
},
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    };

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex,
    cancel: '[contenteditable]',
})//.disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h1>Sorting A Table With jQuery UI</h1>
<a href='http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/'>Make table rows sortable with jQuery UI</a>

<table id="sort" class="grid" title="Kurt Vonnegut novels">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">1</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1969</p></td><td>Slaughterhouse-Five</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">2</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1952</p></td><td>Player Piano</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">3</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1963</p></td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">4</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1973</p></td><td>Breakfast of Champions</td><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="InputBox_RowClass">5</td><td><p contenteditable='true'>1965</p></td><td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td><td>A</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```